# setRoot() not working after dismiss modal in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, modal-dialog, root

i tried to setRoot after dismiss modal in ionic 3, but its not working perfectly.
i want to make root /opportunities/opportunities-detail change to opportunities/opportunities-unit after open and select modal value

its only works if i use main root navigation like this

```
this.app.getRootNav().setRoot('OpportunitiesUnitPage');
```

but i dont want to change my root before it, i just want to push new root after open the modal
i tried this,  but its not works

```
 this.navCtrl.push('OpportunitiesUnitPage', {});
```

this is the full code that i have done
oppotunities-detail.ts

```
let modalQualifyVerify = this.modalCtrl.create('OpportunitiesNotifPage', {
       meta: this.meta,
       opportunity:this.opportunity,
       selection: this.savedSelection,
       status: 'unitSelect'}, {cssClass: 'select-modal-unit' });
     modalQualifyVerify.onDidDismiss(data => {
     });
     modalQualifyVerify.present();
```

oppotunities-notif.ts

```
changeUnit(){
this.viewCtrl.dismiss(null);
this.navCtrl.push('OpportunitiesUnitPage', {
  meta: this.meta,
  opportunity: this.opportunity,
  selection: this.savedSelection
});
```

}

can you guys helpp me how to figure it out? thankyou :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found the aswer guys,
i setroot after i dismiss the modal, this is the full code that i made

oppotunities-notif.ts

```
changeUnit(){
var dismissData = {status:'unitPage'};
this.viewCtrl.dismiss(dismissData);
```

}

opportunities-detail.ts

```
 let modalQualifyVerify = this.modalCtrl.create('OpportunitiesNotifPage', {
      meta: this.meta,
      opportunity:this.opportunity,
      selection: this.savedSelection,
      status: 'unitSelect'}, {cssClass: 'select-modal-unit' });
    modalQualifyVerify.onDidDismiss(data => {
      if(data.status == "unitPage"){
        this.navCtrl.push('OpportunitiesUnitPage', {
            meta: this.meta,
            opportunity: this.opportunity,
            selection: this.savedSelection
          });
      }
    });
    modalQualifyVerify.present();
```